# Magento 2 Content blocks and pages won't load

Tags: magento2, static-block, cms-pages, cli

Ground floor beginner here. 
Fresh M2.2.3 install, the first thing I did was to change to production mode.

I did these steps:

1. opened app/etc/env.php
2. Set 'MAGE_MODE' to 'production'
3. Cleared all cache, cleared indexes, and cache the server.
4. Opened my Admin
5. Navigated to: content > block and pages >  loading PROBLEM occurs here.

Neither "blocks" nor "pages" will load in the Admin, I just get the spinning vortex of loading. 
BTW: "Widgets" seems to load fast, no waiting.

I am not familiar with the command line but I am comfortable finding and changing documents on the backend server.

Anyone know a fix?
Thank you so much!

**-UPDATE: 5/28/18-** 
 
Here is an update to my problem.
error list:

`Error list ,

Refused to execute script from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.709 (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://dondelevagallery.com/pub/static/version1526747762/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/editing/editor.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.713 (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://dondelevagallery.com/pub/static/version1526747762/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.715 (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://dondelevagallery.com/pub/static/version1526747762/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.736 (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://dondelevagallery.com/pub/static/version1526747762/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/multiselect.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.736 (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://dondelevagallery.com/pub/static/version1526747762/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/range.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.737 (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://dondelevagallery.com/pub/static/version1526747762/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.790 (index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://dondelevagallery.com/pub/static/version1526747762/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/grid/massactions.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:21.711 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/grid/editing/editor" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.715 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.716 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.716 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.735 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "ui/grid/sticky/sticky" template requested by "cms_block_listing.cms_block_listing.listing_top".
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.736 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/multiselect" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.736 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/range" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.737 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
00:02:21.790 console-output-handler.js:34 [2018-05-28 12:02:21] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Ui/js/grid/massactions" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34`

I asked my ISP said they tried to fix it but that I should contact a Magento expert, so I came back here.

hopefully I am not too frustrating and helpless but I appreciate all your advice. Maybe there is a link you can send me me too or advise what I should learn first, like using PuTTY or CLI... Thank you so much for your help all.

Comment: Try this commands `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento setup:static:deploy` Then `php bin/magento cache:flush` You can learn more from here : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

Change MAGE_MODE to "default" at app/etc/env.php, then run through cli `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` from project root.

Comment: I haven't ever used the command line, is there another way?  I am not opposed to using the CLI. I just need to set it up and all, I appreciate your patience. BTW   My  Mage Version is 2.2.3

Comment: I just installed everything, Set up my ssl key in PuTTY and entered: php bin/magento deploy:mode:show   (so I can see my mode.)  PuTTY  returns: Could not open input file: bin/magento  .  thanks

Comment: Did you do it from project root? Run lc -l command, what do you see?

Comment: I still get the: Could not open input file: bin/magento

Comment: From control panel I don't see a " PHP folder" in my "public_html folder".  However I do see a "phpserver folder".

Comment: I checked with my ISP to get some help. They tried to help me but said it was was more complicated then they could handle.  Below is the error list they sent me:   >

Comment: So I got a CLI established: next I typed in the above  `code:  php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production `and got this responce--" _Could not open input file: bin/mageneto_

Answer (score 1):

Please deploy the static content by using below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Were do i write this?

Comment: you have to run the command on Magento root folder using putty or CMD

Comment: So I got a CLI established: next I typed in the above  `code:  php bin/magento static-content:deploy -f `and got this response--" _Could not open input file: bin/mageneto_  I also tried using sudo but I got the same response. How do I find if I am in the root?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much all!!!!
I learned a lot on this venture.
So what fixed it for me was setting the MAGE_MODE to production, manually. 
Then runing the Cli:

```
/usr/local/php71/bin/php-cli /home/cpanelusername/public_html/bin/magento static-content:deploy
```

I wasn't a the root before.

Thank you again, @Kamlesh, @Stephan, @Kunj !